# How to show image in custom grid in magento 2 backend using layout only?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, grid, grid-layout, listing

I am trying to display image on custom grid in `back-end` using `layout` but not idea how to show it. I know image show using `ui_component` & `block` but i need to show using `layout` only. Please help me.

Comment: why you don't want to add image using ui_component...

Comment: Because i want data filters in grid.

Answer (score 0):

We found solution for this. images show in grid using renderer.

//add below code to your layout.

```
<block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="image">
<arguments>
     <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Image</argument>
     <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">image</argument>
     <argument name="renderer" xsi:type="string">Vendorname\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\Renderer\Image</argument>
</arguments>
 </block>
```

// Add below code to your block file

```
<?php

namespace Vendorname\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\Renderer;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\AbstractRenderer;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class Image extends AbstractRenderer
{
    private $_storeManager;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Backend\Block\Context $context, StoreManagerInterface $storemanager, array $data = [])
    {
        $this->_storeManager = $storemanager;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_authorization = $context->getAuthorization();
    }

    public function render(DataObject $row)
    {
        if($row['image']) {
        $mediaDirectory = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);

        $imageUrl = $mediaDirectory.'demo/images/'.$row['image'];

        return '<img src="'.$imageUrl.'" width="100"/>';

        }
    }
}
```

Happy Coding!!